# how to get date format in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

Hi I have a file with a few thousand rows to be added into a MySQL database. There are date values in the rows which are in dd/mm/yyyy, d/mm/yy format but I need them to be in yyyy-mm-dd format.

eg: '11/04/2011', needs to become '2011-04-11', in every row
7/04/2011', needs to become '2011-04-07', in every row

Is there a simple way to do this in notepad++ using find and replace.

Comment: Find: `(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d{4})`   Replace with: `$3-$2-$1`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Notepad++:

Find: `([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)`

Replace: `\3-\2-\1`

Comment: If you know the existing dates are fixed width (eg. day and month are zero prefixed if less than 10) then specifying exact counts for repetition will reduce the possibility of false positives: `([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})`.

Comment: This will find both cases, but won't correctly replace both cases (need to be able to append a 0 if the day is a single digit).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a messy expression, you should do this in two passes. First you want to find/replace the dates with a two digit day:

```
Find: ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})
Replace: \3-\2-\1
```

Then you want to do the same for a single digit day:

```
Find: ([0-9]{1})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})
Replace: \3-\2-0\1
```

**Please note that both the find AND replace values are different in each example (one uses a leading 0 and one doesn't for the replace). If you run the second pass first, you will end up with a lot of false positives.**

Answer (score 0):

find : `(\d*)/(\d*)/(\d\d\d\d)`

replace : `($3)-($1)-($2)`